# How can I explain why we use 'having' in 'consider having' and 'have' in 'I'd rather have'?

Tags: have

I'd like a simple explanation as to why we use present continuous in some phrases and present simple in others. For example 'I recommend you consider *having* it remodeled' vs 'I'd rather not *have* it...' or 'I recommend putting it...' vs 'I recommend you to put it..'

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the possibility of having it remodeled.

Answer (score 3):

These are not finite (tensed) forms but non-finite (untensed) forms heading subordinate non-finite clauses. Which specific form is required is determined by the verb heading the superordinate clause in which the subordinate clause is embedded.

> I recommend you consider having it remodeled

*Having* here is not "present continuous"—that construction requires some form of *BE* before the *-ing* form. The *-ing* form *having*, without *BE*, is the non-finite form which the verb *consider* (when it is used in this sense) requires as head of its subordinate complement clause.

Traditional grammar, which characterizes the verbs heading non-finite clauses according to the syntactic role the clause plays, gives this use of the *-ing* form the name *gerund*—a non-finite form acting externally as a noun.

> I'd rather not have it

*Have* here is not "present simple", but an infinitive, the non-finite form required by the modal verb *would* as head of its subordinate complement clause. The complement of any modal verb is always an infinitive unmarked with *to*.

> I recommend putting it...
>   I recommend you to put it ...
>   I recommend you put it ...

*Recommend* licenses three sorts of complements:

> gerund (*putting*)
>   marked infinitive (*to put*)
>   unmarked infinitive (*put*) — *traditional grammar calls this a 'present subjunctive', but the form is identical with the infinitive in every verb. Since in present-day English this form complements only verbs which 'require' or 'urge' some action, it might plausibly be considered an imperative—which is also identical with the infinitive.*

Comment: +1 You can't say that too often. It's the **Verb** that determines almost everything in a clause, or a sentence. Find the verbs and their relationships and you have the skeleton of the sentence.